# Excel recognising E in a number as part of a serial number

Tags: oracle, export-to-excel, scientific-notation

I am working with serial numbere that have an E as part of the number. (e.g 123456.7E2021) If I format the cells as text Excel will display the number correctly.

The problem is I am exporting the serial numbers from Oracle and I have to save the file in a previously saved workbook and when I do excell automaticly applies Euler's Number rule so I am not able to change the number back with formating.

Comment: Although *e* (the base of the natural logarithm) is indeed known as Euler's number, it seems more probable you're running into trouble with [E notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation), which has nothing to do with that. You probably want to remove the tag for that and add `excel`.

Comment: Is your "serial number" actually a number data type or is it a string? Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] that includes: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statement for your table; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data that is representative of your serial numbers; and details of how you are exporting the values from Oracle into Excel. Are you performing a query and copy-pasting? If so, what is the query you are using? Are you using a VBA script? Is so, what is the script you are using? Something else? If so, what?